# Make images switch to their assigned layouts

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to **make each image switch the current layout to a layout assigned to the image.** I'm stuck on assigning IDs to images (after which I *will* create corresponding layouts (and assign IDs for them so I can have a `method` that `listen`s for clicks identifying the ID of clicked image to switch to needed `layout` using the layout's ID).

(My *idea* is to make an app that starts as a fullscreen grid of photos switching to their assigned layouts containing text and pictures.(No padding, animations, settings, splashscreen, scrolling.)).

```
package com.rogcg.gridviewexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    private class myClass implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(parent.getId()) {
                case R.id.listview1:
                    break;
                case R.id.listview2:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        items.add(new Item("Image 1", R.drawable.laptop_50));
        items.add(new Item("Image 2", R.drawable.toast_50));
        items.add(new Item("Image 3", R.drawable.rekawice_50));
        items.add(new Item("Image 4", R.drawable.strych));
        items.add(new Item("Image 5", R.drawable.ksiegozbior_50));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return items.get(i).drawableId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        }

        picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);

        Item item = (Item) getItem(i);

        picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
        name.setText(item.name);

        return v;
    }

    private class Item {
        final String name;
        final int drawableId;

        Item(String name, int drawableId) {
            this.name = name;
            this.drawableId = drawableId;
        }
    }
}
}
```

[SquareImageView.java](http://pastebin.com/VnBKB7QS)

activity_main.xml pastebin.com/0c9mZygz

gridview_item.xml pastebin.com/hQ0HVPDn

"grid of photos": https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yGfi.png

Comment: So, is there any problem?

Comment: @StenSoft yes this code doesn't work.More specifically this seems to be wrong because `listview1` and `listview2` is underlined in red by `Android Studio`.I know it means that it can't find anything with such IDs but I have no idea how to assign these IDs to pictures

Comment: Resource IDs are specified in resource XMLs with `<item type="id" name="listview1"/>` or are generated from layout XMLs when you use `android:id="@+id/listview1"`. You can assign these IDs to views with `setId` (the latter actually assigns it automatically).